# Making buttons disappear and reappear on add / remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is for an image slideshow with 'next' and 'previous' buttons, the issue is I want the 'previous' button to be hidden when the first image is showing, and the 'next' button to be hidden when the last one shows. I am using a class 'active' to determine which image is displayed, all other images are hidden by default:

```
<button id="prev">previous</button>
<img src="img/1.jpeg" class="one active">
<img src="img/2.jpg" class="two">
<img src="img/3.jpeg" class="three">
<button id="next">next</button>
```

Here is the script I currently have, the if statement being the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if($('.one').hasClass('active')) {
  $('#prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

function nextImg() {
    var active = $('img.active');
    var next = active.next();
    active.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
}

function prevImg() {
    var active = $('img.active');
    var prev = active.prev();
    active.removeClass('active');
    prev.addClass('active');
}

$('#next').click(nextImg);
$('#prev').click(prevImg);

});
```

This hides the 'previous' button upon loading, but the button remains hidden even when the 'active' class moves to the next image. I've tried 'toggle' and adding an 'else' statement and setting the button's visibility to 'visible' again, but once it disappears I can't make it come back.

I was hoping to find a simple fix for my existing code, but I'm also open to a different method that would work better for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a slideshow, I suggest you use `display` instead of `visibility` for your images...

The difference is that the space of an "invisible" element is reserved.
With `display:none;`, this space is freed.

And since you use classes, I suggest you use CSS to set these attributes.

In the snippet below, I also took care of the dissapearance of the "next" button when the last image is displayed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function showButtons(){
    if ( $("img").first().hasClass("active") ){
      $("#prev").addClass("hidden");
    }
    else if ( $("img").last().hasClass("active") ){
      $("#next").addClass("hidden");
    }
    else{
      $("button").removeClass("hidden");
    }
  }

  function nextImg() {
    var active = $('img.active');
    var next = active.next();
    active.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
    showButtons();
  }

  function prevImg() {
    var active = $('img.active');
    var prev = active.prev();
    active.removeClass('active');
    prev.addClass('active');
    showButtons();
  }

  showButtons();
  $('#next').click(nextImg);
  $('#prev').click(prevImg);

});
```

```css
img{
  width:60px;
  display:none;
}
.active{
  display:inline-block;
}
.hidden{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="prev">previous</button>
<img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/numbers-1-icon-22.png" class="one active">
<img src="http://icons.veryicon.com/ico/System/Icons8%20Metro%20Style/Numbers%202%20filled.ico" class="two">
<img src="http://www.ifixer.gr/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Numbers-3-filled-icon-300x300.png" class="three">
<button id="next">next</button>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It's amazing how simple it is once you see the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are experiencing your issue is because you have set the visibility of your button to hidden, but never restored it. A quick fix could be to move the visible/hidden logic to your prevImg and nextImg functions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function showPrevButton() {
    if($('.one').hasClass('active')) {
      $('#prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    } else {
      $('#prev').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
}

function nextImg() {
    var active = $('img.active');
    var next = active.next();
    active.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
    showPrevButton();
}

function prevImg() {
    var active = $('img.active');
    var prev = active.prev();
    active.removeClass('active');
    prev.addClass('active');
    showPrevButton();
}

$('#next').click(nextImg);
$('#prev').click(prevImg);

});
```

Comment: For some reason, this code doesn't hide either of the buttons.